# Unable to assign LUIS authoring API

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS instance with one account, and am trying to migrate it to another account.  The original LUIS instance has an authoring and prediction endpoint, both backed by Azure resources, not by the trial key.

When I create the new instance, for some reason, I cannot add an Azure resource authoring endpoint. You can see the two images here.  The first image is from the original LUIS instance, where I have both an existing authoring resource shown, and the ability to add another one.  The second image is from the new account, where under the authoring resource tab, there is no option to add an authoring resource.

I've tried using the API to list my Azure LUIS authoring endpoint and assign it to the resource to no avail, with the instructions found 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription#assign-an-authoring-resource-in-the-luis-portal-for-all-apps) with no luck.  When I list the available resources to add, just my general LUIS instance in Azure is listed.  I have an 'authoring' instance, but the API doesn't find it.  Even assigning the general purpose instance to my LUIS app doesn't work.  The API call succeeds, but when I go back to the LUIS portal, there is still no authoring endpoint.  I created the LUIS app as 'both' when creating.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How new is the new account? Is it possible that it's an unmigrated account? Also, have you tried in the preview portal? https://preview.luis.ai/

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried the new portal. In there it is the same.   I have a prediction resources tab, but not an authoring tab.  I've created an Azure LUIS authoring resource but cannot add it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, somehow I am able to add the resource in the preview site:
preview.luis.ai.

thanks!

Comment: Would you like to accept your own answer or would you like me to post this as an answer for you to accept?

Comment: My bad, feel free to post as answer and I will accept.   Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @KyleDelaney I take that back.  When I log in to the portal today (regular or preview), the resources I added yesterday are gone and its back to the trial key.  When I go to add an Azure resource, it doesn't allow me to select any of my existing resources

Comment: Now it seems in the old portal there is another version of the app there, with the resources.  This is entirely confusing lol

Comment: Ok, I hate to be unnecessarily complicated.  But now I log in and it is there again.  It goes away and comes back.  There is something strange happening for sure

Comment: When it is there, you see it in both the old and the new portal, right?

Comment: Did you migrate your account? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-authoring

Comment: Yes I have migrated.  As another example, I log into the old website and see the authoring resource today. In the preview, I can see the skeleton placeholder flash in the UI, then disappears.  Go back to the old, then the new again, then it is there in the new once more

Comment: Suppose it's a caching issue. Do you get any consistency in an incognito window?